# what is the safest way to set an input value with liquid?

Tags: javascript, shopify, xss, liquid

here is what I'm doing:

```
<input value="{{ value | strip_html | escape }}">
```

looking at examples it seems like escape might be enough

https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/search?p=1&q=escape&unscoped_q=escape

but it doesn't escape `<`, `>`, and `"` for instance.

(obviously no escape leads to an XSS)

I'm using the latest liquidjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will update this answer if things change but seems like `| escape` is enough and there isn't a way to get out of a double-quoted attribute (`""`) without a double quote, I just need to make sure I'm using double quotes. so this should be enough:

```
<input value="{{ value | escape }}">
```

to be clear `<input value="{{ value }}">` exposes you to an [XSS vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)).

you can see the differences for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/h80radfu/

Answer (score 0):

Other escaping filters that may suit your needs are:

- `handle` (or `handleize`): Formats a string into a handle.
- `url_encode`: Converts any URL-unsafe characters in a string into percent-encoded characters.
- `url_escape`: Identifies all characters in a string that are not allowed in URLS, and replaces the characters with their escaped variants.
- `url_param_escape`: Replaces all characters in a string that are not allowed in URLs with their escaped variants, including the ampersand (&).
- `json`: Converts a string into JSON format. (Note: simple variables, such as strings, become escaped strings wrapped in double-quotes)

Give these a spin and see if any of them meet your requirements.

Sources:
https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters
https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/additional-filters

Comment: the value is a previously-provided free-form user input, handle/url encode/escape/etc./json would change the resulting value. I just want to escape the value so that there is no XSS.

Comment: There will be no XSS on raw form input. It's treated as raw text and not interpreted by the HTML parser in the browser. You only need to escape user input when you're displaying that user input in an HTML element.

Comment: Then if the only thing you're concerned about is the double-quotation-mark (`"`), just use `{{ value | replace: '"', '&quot;' }}`, no?  Also, double-check that `escape` isn't doing its job - now that I think about it, there are quite a few sites that I've seen that use constructs like `data-something="{{ complex_thing | escape }}"`, and quotes *do* get escaped properly.  Your browser's dev tools may be showing you parsed values even though the underlying HTML is actually escaped

Answer (score 0):

Shopify will escape most values by default. However, many Liquid libraries (like the Ruby Gem) do not and will require explicit use of the `| escape` filter.

So in Shopify, this will be enough

```
<input value="{{ value }}">
```

For every other Liquid implementation do

```
<input value="{{ value | escape }}">
```

You do not need the `strip_html` as that will mangle your user input should a user need to put HTML characters in their text.